# Тире необходимо?

Tags: пунктуация

Кому-то везет, а кому-то - нет.
Тире необходимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо ли тире? Вовсе нет. Предложение прекрасно смотрится и без него. Это параллельные конструкции, два безличных предложения в составе сложного. Слово НЕТ заменяет сказуемое НЕ ВЕЗЁТ.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что да. Хотя бы для того, чтобы интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое.